# os.path.exists()- passing variables fron another script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using one script which includes this:

```
if not os.path.exists(copy):
    print "Wrong path-directory name"
```

I have an other which includes all the variables:

```
copy = /users/.../.... e.t.c.
```

When i call the second one through the first one i am taking all the desired results except this with the wrong path. the message is:

```
if not os.path.exists(copy):
NameError: name 'copy' is not defined.
```

Why my script cannot recognize the copy path when it is inside the os.path module? What should I modify?

Comment: Are they both python scripts? or are you calling your python program from inside another script?

Comment: I guess you will have to import the Variable 'copy' in the file which contains if not os.path.exists(copy):.... Are you importing copy in it ?

Comment: sorry I am beginner and I didnt think to give more details. yes I use only python scripts.. yes I have have to import the Variable 'copy' in the file which contains if not os.path.exists(copy) BUT i dont want to. I want to have all the variables to the variables.py and call it. for the other things it works only with the os.path.exists there is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variables.py:

```
copy="/users/.../.... e.t.c."
```

You have a few options:

script.py

```
import variables
print copy # NameError: name 'copy' is not defined
print variables.copy # /users/.../.... e.t.c.
```

or:

```
from variables import copy
print copy # /users/.../.... e.t.c.
```

or:

```
from variables import *
print copy # /users/.../.... e.t.c.
```

or:

```
execfile("variables.py")
print copy # /users/.../.... e.t.c.
```

the issue was just that when you import `variables`, everything in that file belongs to `variables`, so you access it with `variables.copy`.

If you don't want to do this you can explicitly import just that variable, with `from variables import copy`, then it will be imported as `copy`. This hides information from whoever is reading the code a little bit, as they might be mislead into believing that `copy` is a local variable, when in fact it's being defined elsewhere.

The next method does the same as the second, but it imports *all* of the defined objects from `variables`. This is even worse than the second method, as they can't even see which variables are coming from the `import`.

The fourth method just runs the `variables.py` file asif the script were being dropped straight into the code at the location of the `execfile` call. This is even less transparent than the 3rd method. Please don't use this for doing what you want to do.

**My preference would be the first method, as it makes it easy to see where everything is coming from, and personally, I thing the `from X import *` style of importing is terrible, and the last one is just horrible.**

Comment: yes it is. Thank YOU. one more question I have but i should add code can I make an other question but how you will see it? Should i add it here?

Comment: @Kostas If it's related to this question, then edit your question to contain the new stuff